# Trying to make all content responsive from MobileFirst to 1080p screen resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

As it stands I am currently trying to make my entire content to be responsive, I have managed to make the background responsive using different @media resolutions which is getting the results I want, however, I have noticed my image that is in the foreground is not scaling with it, what I have done to get it to kind of scale with everything is put that one image in its own @media, but I wonder if that is the correct approach otherwise my CSS file is going to have a bunch of @media's from mobile devices to 1080p screen resolutions, I am using Bootstrap 5.1.

Please see my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sheldon's Online Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      </nav>
    </div>

      <div class = "container">
        <div class = "profile-pic">
          <img src= "Images used/Profile Pic.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt = "No Image"/>
        </div>
          <img src= "Images used/photo-1542831371-29b0f74f9713.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt = "No Image"/>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "container-sm">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <div class = "container-sm-t">
        <p>I am Sheldon Aldridge and I am a Front-End Web
         Developer. Technology has always been a passion of mine.
         In 2014 I earned my diploma in 3D animation and this involved
         using technology platforms to create and design characters, assets,
         and environments, I loved experimenting with colours and creating
         something from my imagination.<br />
         <br />
         I discovered web design and web development in 2020, I went through
         a web design course through Shaw Academy, Front-End Web development course
         through Udemy and a UX/UI design course through UCT.
       </p>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
  margin:auto;
}

.navbar
{
  background-color: #2A3956;
  box-shadow: inset 0.5px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #02d3f6;
  border: 1px solid #02d3f6;

}

.navbar-default
{
  border:0;
}

.container
{
  padding:0px;
}

.img-fluid
{
  border: 1px solid #02d3f6;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container-sm
{
 background-color: #2A3956;
 box-shadow: inset 0.5px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #02d3f6;
 border: 1px solid #02d3f6;
 min-height: 340px;
}

.profile-pic
{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32%;
  margin-top: 50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.img-thumbnail
{

  border: 1px solid #02d3f6;
  max-width: 50%;
  border-radius: 100px;

}
.container-sm h1
{
  color:#07DD45;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left: 41%;
}

.container-sm-t p
{
  color:#07DD45;
  font-size:14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-width:10px
}

.container-md
{
 background-color: #2A3956;
 box-shadow: inset 0.5px 0.5px 5px 0.5px #02d3f6;
 border: 1px solid #02d3f6;
}

.container-md h1
{
  color:#07DD45;
  margin-top: 3%;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left: 41%;
}

.container-md-grid
{
  column-rule-color:#02d3f6;
  display: table;

}

.row
{
  column-count: 5;
  margin-right:-4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.column
{
background-color: #02d3f6;
max-width: 60px;
max-height: 137px;
}

.column p
{
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}


@media (min-width: 576px)
{
.container, .container-sm
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
{
.profile-pic
  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 53%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.container, .container-md, .container-sm
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px)
{
.profile-pic
  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 44%;
    margin-top: 59%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
{
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
{
  .profile-pic
    {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 44%;
      margin-top: 59%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm,.container-xl,
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
  .profile-pic
    {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 44%;
      margin-top: 59%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px)
{
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm,.container-xl, .container-xxl
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px)
{
  .profile-pic
    {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 44%;
      margin-top: 59%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1080px)
{
.container, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xxl
  {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1080px)
{
  .profile-pic
    {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 44%;
      margin-top: 59%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make everything under one @media or would I have to go the long route to achieve what I want, to make all content responsive?

here is the bootstrap 5.1 documentation that I have been referencing - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_containers.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many useful classes for images, i.e. `w-100`, `img-fluid`, etc. Try them in your code and see whether it helps.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/images/